# load class not in classpath dynamically in web application - without using custom classloader

Tags: java, classloader

I am developing a web application.

1. The web application generates java classes on the fly. For example it generates class `com.people.Customer.java`
2. In my code, I dynamically compile this to get com.people.Customer.class and store in some directory say `repository/com/people/Customer.class` which is not on the classpath of my application server.My application server(I am using WebSphere Application Server/Apache Tomcat etc) picks up the classes from the `WEB-INF/classes` directory. The Classloader would use this to load the classes.
3. After compilation I need to load this class so that it becomes accessible to other classes using it after its creation.
4. When I use `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().loadClass(com.people.Customer)` obviously the Classloader is not able to load the class, since its not on the classpath(not in `WEB-INF/classes`). Due to similar reasons, `getResource(..)` or `getResourceAsStream(..)` also does not work.

I need a way to :

Read the class `Customer.class` maybe as a stream (or any other way would do) and then load it. Following are the constraints:

1. I cannot add the repository folder to the `WEB-INF/classes` folder.
2. I cannot create a new Custom ClassLoader. If I create a new ClassLoader and this loads the class, it will not be accessible to its parent ClassLoader.

Is there any way of achieving this?

If not this, in the worse case, is there a way of overriding the default class loader with a custom class loader for web applications the same classloader should be used to load applications throughout entire lifecycle of my web application.

Appreciate any solution :)

Comment: Why can't you add it to the WEB-INF/classes folder?  That's the real solution.  Is it "can't" under any circumstances or "won't" or "would rather not"?

Comment: @duffymo: your assumption is that the webapp is deployed in expanded mode and that the webapp has write permissions to the file system. That's not always the case in production environments. Writing files to WEB-INF/classes is not a good solution

Comment: Nope, I'm not assuming any of that - your clairvoyant interface is down, mhaller.  I'm arguing that the WAR should be repackaged to include all the necessary .class files and redeployed.  I'd like to see the use case where it's necessary to create something as obvious as Customer on the fly.  Instances?  Yes.  Classes?  No, I'm not buying it.

Comment: Well, I know about that use case because we're doing exactly that. Our customers deploy new, generated code at runtime, independent of the web application where this code is running in. An appserver within an appserver so to speak. That's why I understand the request of swdeveloper, although I must admit that it's unusual and of course I wouldn't go for something like that in a "normal" web application.

Comment: The class "Customer" may not be a suitable example if you think "static" domain models. But suppose you're building a multi-tenant capable solution where each tenant is able to model and adjust his own domain model on the fly -> code gen -> dyn. class loading. S.th. along those lines...

Comment: Classes loaded by the child classloader *will* be accesible to the parent classloader (through Reflection API or by casting to a known interface). What you cannot do is *refer* to these classes in code, but that is not a problem as you could not anyway: they are generated on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

You need a custom class loader to do this, and in this classloader you need to re-define a method `findClass(String name)`

An example:

```
public class CustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    final String basePath = "/your/base/path/to/directory/named/repository/";

    @Override
    protected Class<?> findClass(final String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        String fullName = name.replace('.', '/');
        fullName += ".class";

        String path = basePath + fullName ;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path);
            byte[] data = new byte[fis.available()];
            fis.read(data);
            Class<?> res = defineClass(name, data, 0, data.length);
            fis.close();

            return res;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            return super.findClass(name);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you'll be load classes from custom location. For example:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("my.pretty.Clazz", true, new CustomClassLoader());
Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
```

Doing this, you tell JVM that class named `my.pretty.Clazz` should be loaded by your custom class loader, which knows **how** and **where from** to load your custom class.
It resolves full class name (like `my.pretty.Clazz`) to file name (in our case: `/your/base/path/to/directory/named/repository/my/pretty/Clazz.class`), then loads obtained resource as a byte array, and finally converts this array to a `Class` instance.

This example is very simple and demonstrates a general technique about how to load custom classes as in your case.
I suggest you to read some articles about class loading, for example [this one](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: **No**

Without a custom ClassLoader, you cannot dynamically load classes.

However, your assumption that you cannot use a custom ClassLoader because your other objects loaded by the WebApp ClassLoader would be unable to use these newly loaded classes is incorrect. All you need is a generic way to use these newly created classes - like a common interface or a meta-description (Beans Introspector for accessing bean properties).

But if you are using third-party libraries like Hibernate and you are dynamically loading entities at runtime which are to be persisted, then you will have a hard time, but imho it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can do this. Just get the web classloader and call the defineClass() method using reflection (it is protected, so be sure to call setAccessible(true) on the method. defineClass() takes a byte array, so it doesn't make any difference where you class is from. Make sure that the class name is unique and you're loading it only once, or you'll have complicated classloading problems.

Comment: You solution is good but the web classloader differ from environement to another and this will make my code non-protable.

Comment: No it won't. defineClass() is a ClassLoader method shared between all classloaders.