# Dynamically loading and instantiating a .class that is not in the classpath

Tags: java

I have two java projects MASTER and PLUGIN. PLUGIN has dependencies to MASTER and its intent is to extend a class found in MASTER, called SCRIPT.

Once I have declared a SCRIPT (myScript), I want to move the .class file to a folder that MASTER can access. I want MASTER to dynamically load and instantiate that class as a SCRIPT.

I've looked for quite a bit and tried different solutions, but I always get a ClassNotFoundException exception.

I would prefer to do this without passing arguments to the JVM at startup.

Is it even possible? This is my current solution: "currentPath" is "etc/etc/myScript.class

```
try {
        OUT.ln("initiating script " + currentPath);
        File file = new File(currentPath);
        File parent = file.getParentFile();

        String name = file.getName().split(".class")[0];


          // Convert File to a URL
        URL url = parent.toURI().toURL();          
        URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};

        // Create a new class loader with the directory
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);

        current = (SCRIPT) cl.loadClass("main.script." + name).newInstance();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load script  " + currentPath);
    }
```

Comment: It was indeed, removed it.

Comment: Does [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473645/load-class-not-in-classpath-dynamically-in-web-application-without-using-custo) help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the class you want to load is defined within a package like:

`main.script.myScript`

and you want to load this class from a folder like `c:/myclasses`,

then you have to put this class to `c:/myclasses/main/script/myScript.class`

and then instantate the classloader with the basefolder like:

```
URL[] urls = new URL[]{new URL("file://c:/myclasses")};
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
```

then the class can be loaded by using the qualified class name:

```
cl.loadClass("main.script.myScript").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()
```

if you want to keep the class at a specific folder without considering the package structure you could do something like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {

            File file = new File("etc/etc/myScript.class");
            String className = file.getName().split(".class")[0];
            String packageName = "main.script.";

            byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of(file.getPath()));
            MyClassLoader myClassLoader = new MyClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
            Object o = myClassLoader.getClass(packageName+className, bytes).getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
            System.out.println(o);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to load script  ");
        }
    }

    public static class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {
        public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
            super(parent);
        }
        public Class<?> getClass(String name, byte[] code) {
            return defineClass(name, code, 0, code.length);
        }    
    }
```